# Newcommand inside foreach: multiple arguments and minipage environment

Tags: macros, minipage, foreach, optional-arguments, arguments

I am trying to define multiple, sophisticated `newcommand`s within a `foreach` loop. This sounds so simple, but why is it so hard ?

Naive attempt:

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{tikz}

\foreach \i in {first,second,third}{
    \expandafter\newcommand\csname\i\endcsname[3]{ % IYO: how readable is this "naive try"?

        command name: \i

        \begin{minipage}[\textwidth]
        first argument: ##1

        second argument: ##2

        third argument: ##3
        \end{minipage}
    }
}

\begin{document}

\first{1}{2}{3}\\

\second{a}{b}{c}\\

\third{Is}{\LaTeX}{cool?}\\

\end{document}
```

this spits:

```
! Undefined control sequence.
l.22     \first
               {1}{2}{3}\\
```

okay, `\newcommand` does not define the command outside the scope of `\foreach`. Does adding `\global` anywhere help? If it does, it could not figure out where to put it. (basic LaTeX rule of thumb: nothing is intuitive)

I must admit that it has been a **headache**. Luckily, Internet is over there, so thank you guys and the Stack websites. Main traps on the way:

- `\global` seems to work only with `\def` so use `\gdef` instead of `\newcommand`
- `\i` will not be expanded as `<the loop counter>` but as `\iota`, so use `\edef` so use `\xdef`
- the `\def` family does not handle arguments specifications the same way, so use `##1##2##3` instead of `[3]` (this is looks soOo much more nice, readable and easy to maintain. I **love** `##1##2##3`. The day I'll need 5 arguments instead of 3, all I'll have to do is just.. never mind.)
- .. I did not even dare asking for optional arguments support. After all, this is only 2016.

In the end, this does compile:

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{tikz}

\foreach \i in {first,second,third}{
    \expandafter\xdef\csname\i\endcsname##1##2##3{ % yum

        command name: \i

        % \begin{minipage}[\textwidth]
        first argument: ##1

        second argument: ##2

        third argument: ##3
        % \end{minipage}
    }
}

\begin{document}

\first{1}{2}{3}\\

\second{a}{b}{c}\\

\third{What}{a}{pain!}\\

\end{document}
```

.. which gets me:

[image]

However, it does not work anymore if I uncomment the lines concerning the `minipage` environment:

```
! Use of \@iminipage doesn't match its definition.
\IfFileExists #1#2#3->\openin \@inputcheck #1 
                                              \ifeof \@inputcheck \ifx \inpu...
l.18     }
```

(by the way, what an impressive clue. Thank you, compiler. Maybe I should make my mind more rigid or there is a danger that you and I will fuse together in harmony, never to be two again.)

In a nutshell, considering the situation:

- Why does `minipage` not work? How may I get it working?
- Is there a way I could ever have `\first`, `\second` and `\third` supporting optional arguments?
- Am I reinventing the wheel? Investigating the wrong way? Is there a better way to do this?

This is it. Thank you for you patience.

Thank you for being here. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using the wrong tool, in my opinion:

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\xforeach}{s m +m}
 {
  \IfBooleanTF{#1}
   {
    \clist_map_inline:on { #2 } { #3 }
   }
   {
    \clist_map_inline:nn { #2 } { #3 }
   }
 }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \clist_map_inline:nn { o }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\xforeach{first,second,third}
 {
  \expandafter\newcommand\csname#1\endcsname[3]{%is this "naive try"?
    \par\bigskip
    command name: #1
    \par\nopagebreak\medskip
    \begin{minipage}{.5\textwidth}
      first argument: ##1

      second argument: ##2

      third argument: ##3
    \end{minipage}
  }
 }

\setlength{\parindent}{0pt} % just for the example

\begin{document}

\first{1}{2}{3}

\second{a}{b}{c}

\third{Is}{\LaTeX}{cool?}

\end{document}
```

As you see, the current item being processed is denoted by `#1` instead of `\i` and `##1` can be used as usual for inner arguments.

[image]

If you need to use a macro expanding to a list, use `\xforeach*`:

```
 \newcommand{\mylist}{first,second,third}

 \xforeach*{\mylist}{<whatever>}
```

Comment: Great ! I already fell in love with `xparse` once because it was easy building optional arguments and their defaults with it. I am so glad there is a dedicated tool to achieve what I needed. Thank you :)

Comment: I have troubles when my list needs to be expanded, like if `\newcommand{\commands}{first,second,third}` then `\xforeach{\commands}{...}`. In this case, I use `\clist_map_inline:Nn`.

Comment: @Iago-lito For that one can use a variant. Let me add it.

Answer (score 3):

You need to protect `\begin` from expanding in the `\xdef`, and minipage width needs `{}` not `[]` other than that you were nearly there, I also fixed up some white space issues.

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{tikz}

\foreach \i in {first,second,third}{%
    \expandafter\xdef\csname\i\endcsname##1##2##3{% yum

        command name: \i

        \noindent\noexpand\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
        first argument: ##1

        second argument: ##2

        third argument: ##3
        \noexpand\end{minipage}%
    }%
}

\begin{document}


\first{1}{2}{3}

\second{a}{b}{c}

\third{What}{a}{pain!}

\end{document}
```

---

Probably I'd use a different loop macro that doesn't introduce unwanted groups:

```
\documentclass{report}

% \usepackage{tikz}

\newcommand\dodefs[1]{%
    \expandafter\newcommand\csname#1\endcsname[3][?]{% yum

        command name: #1

        \noindent\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
        first argument: ##1

        second argument: ##2

        third argument: ##3
        \end{minipage}%
  }%
}

\makeatletter

\@for\i:=first,second,third\do{%

\expandafter\dodefs\expandafter{\i}

}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

%\show\first
\first[1]{2}{3}

\first{2}{3}

\second[a]{b}{c}

\third[What]{a}{pain!}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I'd use a loop macro that does not group the body, (such as `\@for` that is defined in the latex format) then for optional arguments you could use `\newcommand`

Comment: Well, thank you. I am now learning about `\noexpand` and `\@for`. However, I could not compile your second code, getting: `> \first=macro:
->\@protected@testopt \first \\first {?}.
l.31 \show\first` with `pdflatex`. What's wrong?

Comment: @Iago-lito oh nothing that is just `\show` showing the definition of `\first` it's a debuuging print statement, just delete that line, or just hit return and tex will carry on, I'll remove it from the above